# getting value inside the list using sortable

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, local-storage, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to get the value inside the `<li>` tag when the user drags the item on the list. I have modified it to get a unique value through localStoage in order to keep a track of the list but not the exact value like `"Item 1"`. Any help would be appreciated in this.

HTML:

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('items');
Sortable.create(el, {
    group: "localStorage-example",
    store: {
        get: function (sortable) {
            var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group);
            return order ? order.split('|') : [];
            console.log(order);
        },
        set: function (sortable) {
            var order = sortable.toArray();
            localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group, order.join('|'));
            console.log(order);
        }
    }
})
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tz89um73/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `onEnd` callback you can get the dragged list item with `event.item` and use `textContent` to get the inner text:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('items');
Sortable.create(el, {
    group: "localStorage-example",

    onEnd: function (event) {
        var draggedItemText = event.item.textContent;
        alert(draggedItemText);
    },
    
    store: {
        get: function (sortable) {
            var order = localStorage.getItem(sortable.options.group);
            console.log(sortable.toArray());
            return order ? order.split('|') : [];
        },
        set: function (sortable) {
            var order = sortable.toArray();
            localStorage.setItem(sortable.options.group, order.join('|'));
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
<ul id="items">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you limited to javascript or can you also use jQuery UI?

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U67cY/52/) shows how simple it is to implement your wishes with some jQuery : )

So for this HTML

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

We just need 4 lines:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("You moved: " + ui.item.html())}
});
```

Comment: I'm limited to javascript only

Comment: In that case, @Moogs seems to have an excellent answer by now.